# Form table inputs doesn't get aligned in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have HTML form in a table like:

```css
.settings-and-performance-edit-form {
   display: table;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" class="settings-and-performance-edit-form">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="edit-form-standard-dauer">
                <label for="edit-standard-dauer">Standard dauer (Wochen): </label>
                <input type="text" id="edit-standard-dauer">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="edit-form-verlangerung-dauer">
                <label for="edit-verlangerung-dauer">Verlängerung Dauer (Wochen): </label>
                <input type="text" id="edit-verlangerung-dauer">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've tried so look for an answer to this, but couldn't find... Could someone tell me how the inputs could be aligned properly with each other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add each field in each `td` like below

```css
.settings-and-performance-edit-form {
   display: table;
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="post" class="settings-and-performance-edit-form">
<table>
    <tr class="edit-form-standard-dauer">
        <td>
            
                <label for="edit-standard-dauer">Standard dauer (Wochen): </label>
                
            
        </td>
        <td>
                <input type="text" id="edit-standard-dauer">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="edit-form-verlangerung-dauer">
                <label for="edit-verlangerung-dauer">Verlängerung Dauer (Wochen): </label>
        </td>
        <td>
                <input type="text" id="edit-verlangerung-dauer">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Most simply without CSS would be to add the `inputs` in extra `<td>` fields. Something like so

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="edit-standard-dauer">Standard dauer (Wochen): </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="edit-standard-dauer">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="edit-verlangerung-dauer">Verlängerung Dauer (Wochen): </label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="edit-verlangerung-dauer">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```